# collection-repeat creates an element with height:0 and width:0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, win-universal-app

I'm using Ionic framework (v1.2) with Cordova, and testing as an UWP app on the local machine. But it doesn't show the element with the content correctly. All the height and width are set to 0.

Below is

```
<ion-view view-title="title">
<ion-content>
    <div>Please choose your investment</div>
    <div class="list card">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="{{selectedInvestmentPlaceholder}}"
                value="{{selectedInvestment}}"/>
        </label>
        <a class="item item-text-wrap"
            ui-sref="app.investments.add({referalState: 'app.transactions.add'})">
            A New Investment
        </a>
        <ion-list>
            <div collection-repeat="investment in investments"
                collection-item-width="100%" collection-item-height="20px">
                <div>{{investment.symbol}} - {{investment.name}}</div>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

In the controller, I set investment to an array

```
        $scope.investments = [ { symbol: 'test', name: 'testName' }];
```

But when I run it, the item doesn't show up
[image]

There's no a list after "*A New Investment*".

When I debug it in VS, the DOM shows that width and height are set to 0

[image]

I searched online but don't find any particular issues with height and width of a collection-repeat. And it's official document doesn't mention how to set a correct height and width. And the tutorial I found don't mention that either. Am I missing anything?

My question, what's the issue here and how do I fix it? If you don't encounter this problem before, can you point me how to debug it? The above is how far I can get to.

Thanks.

P.S.
I also replaced `collection-item-width` with `item-width`, `collection-item-height` with `item-height`. But I got the same result.

Comment: While I create an app as @Alex asked, I found that the height/width are set to different values (zero vs non-zero) in Edge and Firefox. I think this may be a bug in Ionic. I created an issue here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6207

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that parent div class="list... and div class="collection-repeat-container" elements don't have height set. It should not be 0.

Comment: I don't understand.http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/ doesn't say I need to set height and width. All it does at most is to set item-height and item-width, which I tried but don't work. I don't really want to hardcode the value. I know div may set the size according to the content. Besides, the position is set to absolute and top is 0. I want to understand how these values are set (width, height, top etch)

Comment: The list might not be visible because the parent container of the collection has height 0. Can you check in the debugger what the height of div class="collection-repeat-container" is? If it is 0 set to it some non zero value and see if this fixes the problem. Or just post your code at http://play.ionic.io/ to share

Comment: I don't create the element div class="collection-repeat-container". It's done by the framework. I check the height and width from he debugger. They're not set at all. I create a simple code here http://play.ionic.io/app/a80f16cd6ade  Interestingly, the height and width are set. But top and left are 0, and position is absolute. That make it at the top left corner and it's covered by other elements.

Comment: It seems width and height are set to 0 in IE and Edge. But I saw they have non zero values in Firefox. In all three browsers, top and left are 0 and position is absolute.

Comment: I took your sample and added the css rule for collection-repeat-container class as below
.collection-repeat-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100px;
}
and the list got shown (I tested under Chrome only)

See http://play.ionic.io/app/3955f7015665 (note the changes in CSS tab)

As I mentioned before, the container div element should have height set in order to be visible.

Comment: I don't think I should go that further to set position, height etc. As I mentioned in other comments, this seems to be a bug in Ionic: width and height are not 0 in Firefox even if I don't set them in css. More over, it doesn't make too much sense to me to hard code height in css. What if users decides to change the font size, the height value in css may be not appropriate any more. I want to let the browser to decide the height. And the document doesn't mean to set those properties in css. It doesn't seem to be designed that way either.

Comment: I don't think that there is a problem with with the ionic. The collection items are shown when the container height is different then zero. It is not required to set fixed height value. You can add the appropriate css rules or smth else to make the container height to be dynamically adjusted as required. For example make it 100%. However this topic is not related to ionic and the initial question.